# python according to the same value combining dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i have a list of dict like this

```
[
{'id': 'A123',
  'feature': {'name': 'jack', 'age' : '18' },
  'create_time': '2022-5-17 10:29:47',
  'is_fast': False},
  
 {'id': 'A123',
  'feature': {'gender': 'male'},
  'create_time': '2022-5-17 10:29:47',
  'is_fast': False},
  
{'id': 'A123',
  'habit': {'name': 'read'},
  'create_time': '2022-5-15 10:29:45',
  'is_fast': False},

{'id': 'A456',
  'feature': {'name': 'rose'},
  'create_time': '2022-4-15 10:29:45',
  'is_fast': False},
  
  {'id': 'A456',
  'habit': {'name': 'sport'},
  'create_time': '2022-3-15 10:29:45',
  'is_fast': False}
]
```

But I want to merge the same "id" values ​​together using something function

The desired output is as follows

```
[

{'id': 'A123',
  'feature': {'name': 'jack', 'age' : '18' ,'gender': 'male'},
  'habit': {'name': 'read'},
  'create_time': '2022-5-19 10:29:47',  #Get the latest time based on the same id
  'is_fast': False},

{'id': 'A456',
  'feature': {'name': 'rose'},
  'habit': {'name': 'sport'},
  'create_time': '2022-4-15 10:29:45',
  'is_fast': False},
  
]
```

How can I merge the same "id" values ​​according to these dictionaries..

Comment: It's just a loop and judicious use of `x.update`.  What have you tried?

Comment: @TimRoberts Hi TimRoberts  oh glad to hear from you, can you give me some more details to let me know how to do it ,thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  If you haven't tried you should try first

Comment: @alexpdev Nice to hear from you can you give me some hints so I can proceed

Comment: @rookie  Looking at your history I see you have asked quite a few questions on SO and have had someone help you on all occasions and yet have never marked one of them as the correct answer.  Picking an answer isn't required but it does make it less likely for people to hellp you in the future when it becomes a pattern

Comment: @alexpdev Thanks for your feedback I'm new to SO and I'll pick the best answer within today Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started...  I put some inline notes to explain what the code is doing.  You still need to implement a date time comparison.

```
def merge_dicts(lst):
    final = {}    #  results
    for row in lst:   # iterate through list
        if row['id'] not in final:   # if current item id hasnt been seen
            final[row['id']] = row   # assign it to results with id as the key
        else:
            record = final[row['id']]  # otherwise compare to data already stored
            for k,v in row.items():   #iterate through dictionary items
                if k not in record:   # if key not in results
                    record[k] = v     # add the key and value
                    continue
                if record[k] == v: continue  # if they are already equal move on
                if isinstance(v, dict):    # if its a dictionary
                    record[k].update(v)    # update the dictionary
                else:  # must be date time sequence so do some datetime comparison
                    """Do some date comparison and assign correct date"""
    return [v for k,v in final.items()]  # convert to list 


print(merge_dicts(lst))
```

output:

```
[
  {
    'id': 'A123', 
    'feature': {'name': 'jack', 'age': '18', 'gender': 'male'}, 
    'create_time': '2022-5-17 10:29:47', 
    'is_fast': False, 
    'habit': {'name': 'read'}
  }, 
  {
    'id': 'A456', 
    'feature': {'name': 'rose'}, 
    'create_time': '2022-4-15 10:29:45', 
    'is_fast': False, 
    'habit': {'name': 'sport'}
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dict.setdefault` method to initialize sub-dicts under keys that don't already exist to avoid cluttering up your code with conditional statements that test the existence of keys:

```
merged = {}
for d in lst:
    s = merged.setdefault(d['id'], d)
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            s.setdefault(k, v).update(v)
        elif v > s[k]: # the dates/times in the input follow alphabetical order
            s[k] = v # later dates/times takes precedence
print(list(merged.values()))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/BlandCarelessPolygons#main.py